# How to get intermediate response from Retrofit API call?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I using Retrofit to making API call. All API call is working fine except one where its returning huge response around 15k records.

Issue is when made call progress bar is being shown infinitely until I get response. And as response too huge getting OOM exception.

As an solution I found that need to use @Streaming annotation. I used that but didn't get intermediate callback. I want API should return chunk of response one by one.

Please help me.

```
public static ServiceInterface getServiceAPIClient() {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(
                    new Interceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request request = chain.request();
                            Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder();

                            builder = request.newBuilder();
                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(PrefsHelper.getAccessTokenEdrm())) {
                                builder.addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, PrefsHelper.getAccessTokenEdrm());
                            }
                            builder.addHeader(API_VERSION, "1.0")
                                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                            request = builder.build();

                            return chain.proceed(request);
                        }
                    }).connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(client)
            .build();

    return retrofit.create(ServiceInterface.class);
}
```

API Method

```
@POST(EdrmConstants.SEARCH_DOCUMENTS)
    @Streaming
    Observable<ResponseBody> searchDocuments(@Body DocumentRequest documentRequest);
```

Comment: I think you should add pagination for good performance.

Comment: Use _MVVM_ architecture with pagination which load your data efficiently. Check [this](https://medium.com/@paulhundal/paging-library-with-android-mvvm-6a3a4d94de72)

Answer (score 0):

15k records is too match.
Retrofit needs time to make http request and makes serialization to your ResponseBody.class

I sure serialization takes main time.

I guess most right solution is to edit request on server side to split data on pages with 200-500 records.